# Need some guidance on how to put data inside a database successfully

Tags: c#, database

I am working on a school project, which needs to be able to put data from a textbox inside a database. I can add the data to a listbox and I am connected to the database, however the new names do not pop up in the database when I refresh them. Can someone help me out? The code is listed below, thanks in advance!

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KillerApp_Calorie
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connectionString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KillerApp_Calorie.Properties.Settings.DBCalorieAppConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private List<Persoon> personen = new List<Persoon>();
        private List<Gerecht> gerechten = new List<Gerecht>();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           /* using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM 
          Persoon", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                DataTable PersoonTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(PersoonTable);
                lb_gebruikers.DisplayMember = "Naam";
                lb_gebruikers.ValueMember = "Id";
                lb_gebruikers.DataSource = PersoonTable;
            } */
         }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             try 
             {
                 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBCalorieApp.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                 con.Open();

                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); // you can define 
     commandText and connection in SqlCommand(defineArea);
                 cmd.Connection = con;              // like; cmd = 
     newSqlCommand("Insert into...",con);
                 string name = tb_naam.Text;
                 string gender = tb_geslacht.Text;
                 cmd.CommandText = "Insert into 
     Persoon(Naam,Geslacht)values('" + name + "','" + gender + "')";

                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 cmd.Dispose();
                 con.Close();

                 lb_gebruikers.Items.Add(name + " - " + gender);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception : " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=

  (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBCalorieApp.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); // you can define 
    commandText and connection in SqlCommand(defineArea);
                    cmd.Connection = con;              // like; cmd = 
    newSqlCommand("Insert into...",con);
                    string gerecht = tb_gerecht.Text;
                    string cal = tb_cal.Text;
                    string inh = tb_inhoud.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Gerechten(Gerecht,Calorieën, 
    Inhoud)values('" + gerecht + "','" + cal + "', '" + inh  +"')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    con.Close();

                    lb_gerechten.Items.Add(gerecht + " - " + cal);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Exception : " + ex);
                }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gerechten.Clear();

            lb_gerechten.DataSource = null;
            //lb_gerechten.Items.Equals("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you shorten this code down to a [mcve]?

Comment: Don't generate SQL using string concatenation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole `AttachDbFileName=` approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `DBCalorieApp`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBCalorieApp;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.